# Two different results of multiplication

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What is the cause of the difference between results of:

```
mov  eax, 0
mov  al,  2
mov  ah,  4
mul  ah;  eax == 0x08
```

and:

```
mov  eax, 0
mov  al,  2
mov  ah,  4
mul  al;  eax == 0x10
```

Comment: The last instruction uses a different register.

Comment: Single-operand forms of the `imul` and `mul` instruction implicitly multiply by the A register of the given size, either `rax` or `eax` or `ax` or `al`. When you specify `ah` as the explicit operand then the implicit operand is `al`. The `al` register is a different register but is also byte sized. So `mul al` multiplies the explicit `al` by the implicit operand which is also `al`.

Comment: Your last comment is wrong however. `al` equal to 2 results in `ax` equal to 4, not 10h.

Comment: @ScottHunter that is quite obvious.

Comment: @ecm This is the result I got.

Comment: @mikerru: Please show a full example and the commands you use to assemble, execute, and examine it.

Comment: Regardless of register's contents. Is using `mul al` not correct? And if so, why?

Comment: @mikerru: It is correct if you want to multiply `al` times `al` (that is, compute `al` squared). Otherwise it is incorrect.

Comment: I you got eax=0x10 then you tested wrong.  I copy-pasted that code into `foo.asm`, and assembled+linked it into an executable with `yasm -felf64 foo.asm` ; `ld -o foo foo.o`, then single-stepped the static executable with GDB.  After the `mul al`, `p $eax` prints 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an 8-bit register `mul` the implied second operand is `al`. In pseudo-code:

`mul ah` means `ax = ah * al`

`mul al` means `ax = al * al`

`x86` assembly makes frequent use of implied operands so it would be a good idea to read up on the instruction reference to be aware of them.

Comment: Sorry for lack of sufficient information in my question. I know this part. The correct question would be: Why `al * al` does not work? I am familiar with C programming where stuff like `a *= a` is working correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing your results but beyond the specification for what ```mul``` is supposed to do, when I actually run your code, the first sets ```ax``` to ```0x0008``` and the second sets ```ax``` to ```0x0004```.

Comment: Regardless of register's contents. Is using `mul al` not correct? And if so, why?

Comment: ```mul al``` is perfectly valid. If you're not getting the expected result of 4 (```al``` * ```al```) I don't know how to explain it.